# Unable to write data from two separate db2 tables into an Elastic Index

Tags: kubernetes, kibana-6

I have created two pipelines for two tables in Kubernetes. Each pipeline corresponds to one table in DB2. They both show under monitoring tab in Kibana. but the index is populated only with the data from one of the tables.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide detail of what you have setup? The pipelines, processors - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey Matt, the problem is solved. There was a mistake with the SQL files of one of the tables. 

Thanks.